# Interrupted time series with continuous treatment

Tags: time-series, intervention-analysis

I am intending to conduct interrupted time series analysis of a public health intervention applied nationally. Since the intervention is national, I'm not intending to do a controlled ITS unless I can generate suitable synthetic controls. However, the magnitude of the intervention (funding allocated) varies between regions. Is there an analytical approach to ITS which allows the intervention 'dose' to vary and to model this dose response on the step and slope changes?

I'm aware of comparable work in DiD - discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/562301/difference-in-differences-with-a-continuous-treatment) for example, but this relies on a suitable control series.

I can see challenges separating the intervention effect on slope and intercept, from the dose response effects on the same outcomes.